# How to fill Google Play Data Safety section when app uses Admob and Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, admob, crashlytics

I have an app that uses Admob for ads and Crashlytics for crash logging. As a developer, I do not collect or share any user data. But I have a couple of questions about Data Safety section:

1. Are Google related services (like Admob and Firebase) considered as a third party?
2. Do I understand correctly that I need to indicate that my app collect and share data because these services do it?

For example, Firebase shares data with its third-party subprocessors:

> Firebase does not transfer this data to third-parties except:
>
> To third-party subprocessors that assist us in providing Firebase services.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/play-data-disclosure

It is very unclear how to fill this form. Lots of confusing information.

Comment: They force us to fill this form but doesn't provide info on their own products. I'm having the same problem, did you find the answer?

Comment: Same here. Since Admob belongs to Google and it is so commonly used, why don't they provide a single check mark that states that the app uses Admob?